# Where are the 11 Poes located that aren't shown on the world Map?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess, zelda-twilight-princess-hd

In Twilight Princess HD the world map shows how many Poes are in each province, and how many of them you've found so far. There are 60 overall, but the world map only accounts for 49 of them. Here what is listed on my world map:

- Faron Province 6/6
- Eldin Province 8/8
- Lanayru Province 19/19
- Desert Province 11/11
- Peak Province 5/5

Where are the remaining 11 Poes located?

(I'm down to one Poe left and have no idea how to find it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Poes inside dungeons are not counted in the totals on the world map. Each dungeon has its own count that you can see when you are inside. Note that the Poes in grottos/mini-dungeons *are* counted in the world map totals. Here are the number of Poes in each dungeon for reference:

- Arbiter's Grounds: 4
- Snowpeak Ruins: 3
- Temple of Time: 2
- City in the Sky: 2